# How to set up the code for Spring + Hibernate dependency injection?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I've a newb to Java coming from C++ / C#.

My project is currently set up like this:

```
org.blah.config
  HibernateConfig.java
org.blah.customer
  Customer.java
  CustomerController.java
  CustomerService.java
```

HibernateConfig sets up the hibernate stuff and exposes the LocalSessionFactoryBean bean.

CustomerController is the REST entry point, it doesn't really have much logic, it sort of just wraps the CustomerService.java (or should I call it CustomerRepository?).

CustomerService.java (or CustomerRepository?) wraps the DB stuff. This is where I have:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

In my CustomerController, if I do:

```
private CustomerService customerService = new CustomerService();
```

it doesn't inject the sessionFactory.

From some samples I've found, people seem to create a CustomerService bean inside of HibernateConfig and then inject that into the constructor of the controller. Is that a good practice? Would I then rename my HibernateConfig to something more specific like CustomerHibernateConfig, etc.

Just trying to get an understanding of how/where to put the config & create the service / repo instance so it can be injected into the controller.

Comment: You should look at the Spring JPA Getting Started Guides; you shouldn't need any Hibernate configuration _at all_, and you should be using the JPA interfaces instead of the legacy Hibernate-specific interfaces. `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a hard question to answer in a few words. You are asking for a whole architecture that will depend a lot on the chosen design pattern, but considering you have controllers and services, let me put it this way. MVS is just a simplification and it's not a perfect approach. This will raise so many more questions like.

- How much logic should go into a controller?
- Should a model contain any logic?
- Should a view contain logic?

Questions like these are very hard to answer, since these are very subjective. Still, I have been using Spring for a while and will give you my advise.

The controller's function is to validate inputs and a redirect to views when needed or to respond to clients' requests. If you got domain logic (aka business logic, business rules, and domain knowledge), the logic that makes business-critical decisions, then it shouldn't be on the controller, it should be on the services.

Now, I would say that you are missing a layer on your architecture, I would definitely add a `DAO`, which is a design pattern that defines a way to decouple the persistence layer of your application. Which is what you would understand as a Repository.

With that said, you only need one HibernateConfiguration and do the corresponding mappings in each model or XML file related to that model. I would advise to use `annotations` instead of XML files.

If you want to learn how to implement a Spring project that uses Hibernate, you can see how easy it is by following this [Baeldung's tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hibernate). That page does have the best guides regarding the usage of Spring.

Comment: Thanks Alain, another commenter recommended using JPA. Trying to figure out what is the preferred method these days. I can't learn everything obviously, so just want to learn the latest & greatest :). I have been using Baeldungs site. The tutorial you pointed me to is "the latest & greatest" :)?

Comment: Yeah, there is a lot, so you must choose the one that fit you best. Here, take a look at this link, it will help you decide. Remember that Hibernate is a JPA implementation that helps with making things easier. https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-difference